# Method not found: 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.get_SelectAsyncMethod()'

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

People I need help I am in a new project in which I am implementing identity server 4 and I am trying to recover the previously created users with asp.Identity that I have in my database to be able to verify when I make an external login from identity server 4. Sorry my english.
My Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{    

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    #region --Identity ASP

    services.AddDbContext<QGoodDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")),ServiceLifetime.Transient);
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<QGoodDbContext>()                   
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    #endregion

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();

    // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
    services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
            //.AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
        }
}
```

When I initialize my database I already have this error

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {          

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            InitializeDatabase(app);
        }

        private void InitializeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                //serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<QGoodDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<QGoodDbContext>();

            }
        }
```

In my `AccountController` i have exception when call  `await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(provider, providerUserId);`

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly QGoodDbContext _context;
        private readonly TestUserStore _users;
        private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService _interaction;
        private readonly IClientStore _clientStore;
        private readonly IAuthenticationSchemeProvider _schemeProvider;
        private readonly IEventService _events;


        public AccountController(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            QGoodDbContext context,
            IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction,
            IClientStore clientStore,
            IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider,
            IEventService events,
            TestUserStore users = null)
        {
            // if the TestUserStore is not in DI, then we'll just use the global users collection
            // this is where you would plug in your own custom identity management library (e.g. ASP.NET Identity)
            _users = users ?? new TestUserStore(TestUsers.Users);
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _context = context;
            _interaction = interaction;
            _clientStore = clientStore;
            _schemeProvider = schemeProvider;
            _events = events;
        }
          public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback()
        {
            try
            {
                // read external identity from the temporary cookie
                var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
                if (result?.Succeeded != true)
                {
                    throw new Exception("External authentication error");
                }

                // lookup our user and external provider info
                var (userTest, provider, providerUserId, claims) = FindUserFromExternalProvider(result);
                var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(provider, providerUserId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Exception is:

> Method not found: 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.get_SelectAsyncMethod()'

Comment: Thanks for you comment , Thankful that you help me

Comment: Are you actually using entity framework 6 or did you just add the tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what was the real problem but after downgrade Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools to version 2.1.4 and updgrade again to last version problem gone.

Answer (score 33):

Hi can you show your packages install ?  I have same problem too when i use EFCore. I solved this when I installed package

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational >= 2.2.0
```

Comment: Down-grading EF core tools didn't work. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational did the deed !

Comment: do not forget to upgrade database provider when upgrade EF Core

Comment: Just went through the pain of this issue just to discover that I've already upvoted this answer and favorited the question lol.

Comment: Worked great.  Odd this isn't included by default.

Comment: An improvement suggestion: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational must be >= 2.2.0. I added my mistake a lower version and that does not solve the problem. When I tried with 2.2.0 it worked immediately.

Comment: for most of the issues, related with .net core 3.1 and .net efcore, it will be usually compatibility issue. choose the right version for efcore.

Answer (score 10):

There are several variations of this problem that exhibit the behavior of `MissingMethodException`, `NotImplemementedException` or `MissingFieldException`.

It appears these are caused by conflicting versions within the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace. For instance, this error can be caused by referencing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` 2.2.0 and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` 2.1.4 in the same assembly.

The solution is to harmonize the versions of nuget package references so that they do not internally reference different versions of EF Core components.

Comment: It's worth mentioning some 3rd party libraries such as Devart have internal references that must also be harmonized.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I implemented my project on AWS Lambda on an .Net Core 2.2 build- I did two things to fix it:

1. Include Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package from NuGet.
2. Included the MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore NuGet package in the top level project - for some reason it get included in the zip file that went up to AWS, even though it was a dependency in a sub project.

I suspect it was the second action that fixed it.